# How to solve: $xu_{x}+u_{y}=1,u(x,0)=2\ln(x)$, $x>1.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the  following problem:

Let $u(x,y)$ be the solution to the Cauchy Problem  $$xu_{x}+u_{y}=1,\;\;u(x,0)=2\ln(x),\quad x>1.$$ Then $u(e,1)=?$  I was trying to solve it by Lagrange's method but could not progress. Can someone point me in the right direction? (A certain property or theorem that I have to use to find out $u(x,y)$.)

Comment: $u(x,y)=2ln(x)-y$.

Comment: How do you get that? Can you refer to the formula used to get it?

Comment: Just some attempt, I can not gurantee the solution is complete, note that given such problem, the first simple idea is to guess $u=2ln(x)+f(y)$, it is lucky this type really gives us a solution here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ougao. Your input has been useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the method of characteristics, let $u(x,y) = u(x(s),y(s)) = f(s)$. Then
$$\dfrac{df}{ds} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \dfrac{dx}{ds} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \dfrac{dy}{ds} = x'(s) u_x +y'(s) u_y = xu_x + u_y$$
Hence, let us set $x'(s) = x$ and $y'(s) = 1$. This gives us
$$x(s) = c_1 e^s; \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, y(s) = s \,\,\,\,\,\,\, f'(s) = 1 \implies f(s) = s + f(0)$$ We also have that $u(x,0) = 2 \ln(x)$. $y=0 \implies s = 0$. Hence, we have that $$f(0) = 2 \ln(x(0)) = 2 \ln(c_1) = f(0) \implies f(0) = 2 \ln(c_1)$$
Hence, $$f(0) = 2 \ln(xe^{-y}) \implies u(x,y) = s + 2 \ln(xe^{-y})$$
$$= y + 2 \ln(x) - 2y$$
$$ = 2\ln(x) - y$$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for the elaborate explanation. I have got it..

Comment: You left out the $s$ term at the end so it's $2\ln(x) - y$, I'll edit it...